# Slow Hazelcast compared to Ehcache

Tags: spring-boot, caching, hazelcast, ehcache

I have developed a basic Spring Boot application and I am currently utilizing the '@Cacheable' annotation for caching purposes.

My caching requirements are quite simple, and I do not need any clustered capability. All I require is basic caching and expiry functionality.

However, when I attempted to use Hazelcast instead of Ehcache, I noticed a significant decrease in performance, with Hazelcast being ten times slower. I am wondering if there are any extra settings that I need to configure to improve Hazelcast's performance.

Example Usage

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SomeDto implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class SomeService {

      @Cacheable("some-cache")
      public SomeDto someMethod(Long id) {
          log.info("Method invoked");
          //Some slow operation
          return new SomeDto(id, "ABC");
      }
}
```

Calculation is like

```
        someService.someMethod(1L); // Heat up

        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            someService.someMethod(1L);
        }
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(t2-t1);
```

```
<network>
    <join>
      <auto-detection enabled="false"/>
    </join>
  </network>

  <map name="some-cache">
    <time-to-live-seconds>20</time-to-live-seconds>
  </map>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with either, but you might have serialization enabled for one and not the other. That would certainly cause a large slow down.

Comment: I am using default config for both.

Comment: Ehcache disabled serialization [by default](https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.10/107.html#by-reference-or-by-value) unless using jcache explicitly (as required by the spec), whereas hazelcast has it [enabled](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/7c3894b1474dba56648cf10ad8441615486fcdea/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/config/AbstractCacheConfig.java#L132) by default (as assumed to be clustered). That causes serialization of copying the entry into and out of the cache, which is a large tax.

Comment: I dont' have the clustered capabilities enabled with hazelcast.`

Comment: I used like <br> ` <network>
    <join>
      <auto-detection enabled="false"/>
    </join>
  </network>`

Comment: I linked to their code where it claims to be on regardless. If you don't need clustering then it seems overkill to use it as not their focus. That's as much as I know; I use [caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) for local caches.